# AWS S3 Generate a presigned url with a md5 check

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im looking to generate a pre signed url with aws s3.
It works fine with some condition (mime type for example) but im unable to use 'Content-MD5'.

I use the node js sdk and put the md5 in fields object.

```js
const options = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Expires: expires,
      ContentType: 'multipart/form-data',
      Conditions: [{ key }],
      Fields: {
        'Content-MD5': params.md5,
      },
} as PresignedPost.Params;

if (acl) {
      options.Conditions.push({ acl });
}

if (params.mimeType) {
      options.Conditions.push({ contentType: params.mimeType });
}
```

But after when I upload the file, I would like AWS to check by itself the uploaded file with the MD5 given in the presigned request but I always have that error :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$Content-MD5", "<md5>"]</Message>
    <RequestId>497312AFEEF83235</RequestId>
    <HostId>KY9RxpGZzRog7hjlDk3whjAbItG/mwhpItYDL7rUNNH4BCXMfmLZsbZIPKivmSZZ3VkWxlgstOk=</HostId>
</Error>
```

My MD5 is generated like that in the browser ( just after recording a video ):

```js
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
reader.onloadend = () => {
  const mdsum = CryptoJS.MD5(reader.result.toString());
  resolve(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(mdsum));
};
```

Maybe it's not the way it works ?

**edit :**

If I add to the upload form data (md5 hash is the same as set in the presigned)

```js
formData.append('Content-MD5', encodeURI(fields['Content-MD5']));
```

the error becomes

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>BadDigest</Code>
<Message>The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received.</Message>
<ExpectedDigest>2b36c76525c8d3a6dada59a6ad2867a7</ExpectedDigest><CalculatedDigest>+RifURVLd61O6QCT+SzhBg==</CalculatedDigest><RequestId>B4FF38D0FCC2E8F2</RequestId><HostId>yS7q200rJpBu48RNcGzsb1oGbDUrN8UK9+gkg6jGMl+EJSGeyQaSCfwfcMRUeNlJYapfmF304Oc=</HostId></Error>
```

answer:

```js
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
reader.onloadend = () => {
          resolve(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(reader.result.toString()))));
        };
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this ?

Comment: hi yes I have edited the message to add the solution